# Deselect path points without selecting new points

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, selections

Working in illustrator. To make this example easier, imagine I'm working with a traced raster image where there are lot of similar colors close to one another. Say I want to select a bunch of points using the lasso tool. I select bunch of points. Oops - I didn't mean to select those 300. Darn it!

Now I need to deselect them. I have two choices. I either try my selection again, and hopefully get precise enough where I have less points that I don't want to select selected. Or I can go point by point, holding down shift, and deselecting.

What I'd like to be able to do is to use the lasso tool again, and deselect from my current selection. I know I can already do this with the lasso tool, but it's almost impossible to do without selecting new points along the way. I want a way to "deselect only", so that I can subtract from my selection with inadvertently adding to it.
 I know that this can be done in Raster editors like PS or Gimp, but there is nothing obvious to me in Illustrator. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay.  I solved this on my own.  In case anyone else runs into this, the solution is to hold down the `ALT` key while selecting, and it does exactly what I want.  This might be different on Mac.  This is super useful.